# can't view video in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, video

In the below code i can view video in mozilla and chrome

but i can't view video in Internet Explorer.

may i know what is problem with my code:

```
<video width="400" height="360" autoplay="autoplay" loop>       
    <source src="Tryteksolutions_captcha-work_from_home.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="Tryteksolutions_captcha-work_from_home.ogv" type="video/ogg" />        
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Tryteksolutions_captcha_work_from_home.swf">            
        <param name="movie" value="Tryteksolutions_captcha_work_from_home.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=Tryteksolutions_captcha-work_from_home.mp4" />         
        <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: What version of IE do you have?

Comment: Do you have [Flash player](http://get.adobe.com/nl/flashplayer/) installed?

Comment: have you add for IE9: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
Also add for chrome: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

Comment: @Shahar I have version IE 10

Comment: @Ex-iT yes i have flash player

Comment: You have an *.ogv file but a video/ogg type, I think this might cause problems, not sure though